# dplyr idiom for "select A, B, max(C) from D group by C"

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a dplyr idiom for SQL group by queries with several result columns. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

df <- data.frame(
  fuel=rep(c("Coal", "Gas"), each=3), 
  year=rep(c(1998,1999,2000), 2),
  percent=c(20,30,40,80,70,60)) 

sqldf("select fuel, year, max(percent) from df group by fuel")

 fuel year max(percent)
 1 Coal 2000           40
 2  Gas 1998           80
```

The sqldf supplies the year that a given fuel reached it's maximum percentage (ignoring ties). What is the best way to do this using `dplyr`? Simply doing:

```
group_by(df,fuel) %>% summarise(max(percent))
```

gives:

```
  fuel max(percent)
1 Coal           40
2  Gas           80
```

and there does not seem to be a place to add an extra result column. I can do it indirectly by using `mutate`:

```
group_by(df,fuel) %>% mutate(maxp=max(percent)) %>% 
   filter(percent==maxp) %>% select(-percent)
```

Is that the best/only way?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(fuel) %>% filter(percent == max(percent))`

Comment: `df %>% group_by(fuel) %>% filter(percent == max(percent)) %>% select(fuel, year, max_percent = percent)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more options

Using `distinct` (this is similar to `slice(which.max(percent))`, but will avoid by group operations and hence probably more efficient)

```
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent)) %>%
  distinct(fuel)

#   fuel year percent
# 1  Gas 1998      80
# 2 Coal 2000      40
```

Or using `filter` (this will select *all* the rows having a maxima)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fuel) %>% 
  filter(percent == max(percent))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: fuel [2]
# 
#     fuel  year percent
#   (fctr) (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1   Coal  2000      40
# 2    Gas  1998      80
```

Or using `top_n` (similar result to `filter(percent == max(percent))`)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fuel) %>% 
  top_n(n = 1, percent) # If percent is always the last column, you can just do top_n(n = 1)

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: fuel [2]
# 
#     fuel  year percent
#   (fctr) (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1   Coal  2000      40
# 2    Gas  1998      80
```

Or using `summarise` and `left_join` (similar result as in the two above)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fuel) %>%
  summarise(percent = max(percent)) %>%
  left_join(., df)

# Joining by: c("fuel", "percent")
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#     fuel percent  year
#   (fctr)   (dbl) (dbl)
# 1   Coal      40  2000
# 2    Gas      80  1998
```

Comment: Only the second gives the same as sqldf for `df <- structure(list(fuel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Coal", 
"Gas"), class = "factor"), year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 1998, 1999, 
2000), percent = c(20, 20, 40, 40, 60, 60)), .Names = c("fuel", 
"year", "percent"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be a good use case for `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(fuel) %>%
  slice(which.max(percent))

## Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
## Groups: fuel [2]

##     fuel  year percent
##   (fctr) (dbl)   (dbl)
## 1   Coal  2000      40
## 2    Gas  1998      80
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(percent)], fuel]
#    fuel year percent
#1: Coal 2000      40
#2:  Gas 1998      80
```